# Attach an Array as an attribute to the Module from the Array of Modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two array of objects namely:-

1. Modules
2. Learners Answered Questions (laq)

In my Modules objects I have a property named quiz which has an array of questions. I want to compare this array with the Learners Answered Questions (laq), an array of nested arrays. If the Learners Answered Questions (laq) has an array that matches with the array of questions in one of the Module.quiz among the array of Modules then I want to attach it an attribute of the Learners Answered Questions(laq). The question in array of questions of the Modules object and the question in the Learners Answered Questions Array of Arrays has a common property of text. Using this I want to compare if both the arrays are equal and if equal then attach the Array from the Learners Answered Questions Arrays as a property to the Modules object.

For example consider:-

```
Modules = [module_1, module_2, module_3]
module1.quiz.questions = [question_1, question_2, question_3]
module2.quiz.questions = [question_4, question_5, question_6]
module3.quiz.questions = [question_7, question_8, question_9]

Learners_Answered_QUestions = [
    [question_7, question_8, question_9], 
    [question_1, question_2, question_3], 
    [question_4, question_5, question_6]
]
```

I cannot compare these arrays directly since they have different properties. So I have to individually check if all the Questions from an Array of one of the  Arrays of Learner_Answered_Questions are having same question in one of the Modules Quiz property.

Here is my code:-

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.modules.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.laq.length; j++){
        if($scope.modules[i].quiz[0].questions.length === $scope.laq[j].length){
            var array_size = $scope.laq[j].length;
            for(var k = 0; k < array_size; k++){
                if($scope.modules[i].quiz[0].questions[k].text === $scope.laq[j][k].quiz_question.text){
                    $scope.attach = true;
                }
                else{
                    $scope.attach = false;
                };
            };
        };
        if($scope.attach === true){
            console.log($scope.attach);
            $scope.modules[i].lq_exists = true;
            $scope.modules[i].learner_quiz = $scope.laq[j];
            console.log($scope.modules[i]);
        }
    };
};
```

My code is not working as well as I want to make it more reliable even if the order of the questions in any of the array is changed.

Here is the sample json format:-

```
module1.quiz = {
"url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz/38/",
"id": 38,
"quiz_name": "Rakesh BIO",
"module_referred": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_courses_modules/98/",
"questions": [
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz_questions/109/",
        "quiz": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz/38/",
        "q_type": "MCQ",
        "text": "What is Rakesh's profession",
        "possible_answers": [
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/306/",
                "text": "cook"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/307/",
                "text": "Accountant"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/308/",
                "text": "IT"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/309/",
                "text": "Plumber"
            }
        ],
        "selected": null,
        "correct": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/308/",
            "text": "IT"
        }
    },
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz_questions/110/",
        "quiz": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz/38/",
        "q_type": "MCQ",
        "text": "What is his place's name?",
        "possible_answers": [
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/310/",
                "text": "Yavatmal"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/311/",
                "text": "Dhule"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/312/",
                "text": "Sangamner"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/313/",
                "text": "Solapur"
            }
        ],
        "selected": null,
        "correct": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/311/",
            "text": "Dhule"
        }
    }
]
```

}

and the Learners_answered_questions JSON:-

```
lqa = [
    {
        "quiz_question": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz_questions/110/",
            "quiz": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz/38/",
            "q_type": "MCQ",
            "text": "What is his place's name?",
            "possible_answers": [
                {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/310/",
                    "text": "Yavatmal"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/311/",
                    "text": "Dhule"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/312/",
                    "text": "Sangamner"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/313/",
                    "text": "Solapur"
                }
            ],
            "selected": null,
            "correct": {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/311/",
                "text": "Dhule"
            }
        },
        "learner": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_learners/4/",
            "user": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_custom_users/4/",
            "profile_picture": null,
            "courses_learning": "Django"
        },
        "chosen_option": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/250/",
            "text": "No Answer Selected"
        }
    },
    {
        "quiz_question": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz_questions/109/",
            "quiz": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz/38/",
            "q_type": "MCQ",
            "text": "What is Rakesh's profession",
            "possible_answers": [
                {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/306/",
                    "text": "cook"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/307/",
                    "text": "Accountant"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/308/",
                    "text": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/309/",
                    "text": "Plumber"
                }
            ],
            "selected": null,
            "correct": {
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/308/",
                "text": "IT"
            }
        },
        "learner": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_learners/4/",
            "user": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_custom_users/4/",
            "profile_picture": null,
            "courses_learning": "Django"
        },
        "chosen_option": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/306/",
            "text": "cook"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please include examples of the 2 JSONs? You did explain everything but it's still a bit hard to follow. Thanks

Comment: yeah sure!! wait a minute.....

Comment: Also, your `$scope.attach` is gonna be either true or false depending on the last comparison ... because you override the previous value in each iteration. Instead you could define it as false before the for loop and set it as true once you found the matching question

Comment: Yes if in the array even if a single question text mismatches I don't want to do further processing.

Comment: Ah ok ... but consider this in your code: if the last comparison matches, `$scope.attach` will be set to true ... even if all the previous ones didn't match.

Comment: Oh yeah!!! thanks.

Comment: Thanks for adding example JSONs. Another question ... is it correct that what you're trying to achieve is to check if moduleX has been completed by comparing all the questions inside moduleX with all the questions inside all of Learners Answered Questions (laq)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172247/discussion-between-shashishekhar-hasabnis-and-protozoid).

Comment: yes I want to have same no of questions and same text for each question in both the arrays being compared. the order does not matter.

Comment: Dang this was difficult lol, hope my answer below is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of this question, I've simplified the JSON's to only what's relevant.

Find a fully working algorithm below (you can play around and change the lengths or texts to check all the cases)

```js
var modules = [
        {
            "id": 38,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "text": "What is Rakesh's profession"
                },
                {
                    "text": "What is his place's name?"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 39,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "text": "What is Protozoid's profession"
                },
                {
                    "text": "What is his car's name?"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    
var laq = [
        [{
            "quiz_question": {
                "text": "What is his place's name?"
            }
        },
        {
            "quiz_question": {
                "text": "What is Rakesh's profession"
            }
        }],

        [{
            "quiz_question": {
                "text": "What is Protozoid's profession"
            }
        },
        {
            "quiz_question": {
                "text": "This shouldnt be attached because not all questions match"
            }
        }]
    ];
    
modules.forEach(function (module) {
 var shouldAttach = true;
 var lqReference = [];
 
 laq.forEach(function (laqItem) {
  var matchedCount = 0;
  module.questions.forEach(function (moduleQuestion) {
   
   laqItem.forEach(function (laqItemQuestion) {

          // console.log(moduleQuestion.text, laqItemQuestion.quiz_question.text, moduleQuestion.text == laqItemQuestion.quiz_question.text);
    if (moduleQuestion.text == laqItemQuestion.quiz_question.text) {
     matchedCount++;
    }

   });

  });
      
    // console.log("should attach1", matchedCount, laqItem.length);
  if (matchedCount == laqItem.length) {
      shouldAttach = true; 
   lqReference = laqItem;
  } else {
   matchedCount = 0;
  }
     
     // console.log("should attach2", shouldAttach);
  // If questions matched but different lengths
  if (shouldAttach && module.questions.length !== lqReference.length) {
   shouldAttach = false;
  }
 });

   // console.log("should attach3", shouldAttach);
 if (shouldAttach) {
  module.lq_exists = true;
  module.learner_quiz = lqReference;
 }
});

console.log(modules);
```